# Tiny zoomable camera with adjustable angle for distance viewing

Tags: webcam, camera

I have an eyesight problem and have trouble seeing presentations on the screen when I'm in conferences or in group meetings. I am currently using an application called Eye Glasses on my iPad for this purpose, which has a nice zoom capability but the problem is that I need to turn it very much toward myself to be able to focus on the presentation (which is usually shown on a screen located on the top of the wall).

I am now looking for a camera/webcam that I can mount on my macbook's screen or on my iPad with the following characteristics:

- It must be tiny (ideally like a spy camera) so it doesn't catch the attention of the presenter or people who are sitting around me (most presenters are not comfortable with being on a camera)
- It must have zoom capability so I can zoom in depending on my distance from the screen
- It must have tilt capability (adjustable angle) so I can focus on the presentation depending on my vertical distance from the screen by just turning the camera (without having to adjust the angle of my macbook's screen or my iPad).

I need to emphasize that I do NOT need to record the presentation. Just seeing the screen would be more than enough for me.

Any ideas as to what options I may have?

Answer (score 1):

The [SQ8 Mini DV Camera 1080P Full HD Car DVR](http://SQ8%20Mini%20DV%20Camera%201080P%20Full%20HD%20Car%20DVR%20%20-%20%20BLACK) is best I could find, it's very small and can run for about 100 minutes at 1080p at 30fps, which should cover most presentations. It comes with its own stand, so if you have a desk, which I assume you do since you can out a laptop down, you can just put it in front of your laptop and stream it to your laptop. The price is also pretty decent. Only questionable thing is that it is from Gearbest, which is an American company but it sells solely Chinese products, and some people have a thing about buying things made and designed in China. But for as long as I have been a customer of Gearbest, everything I've brought so far hasn't ha an issue, so I guess it's your call.

Comment: Note: I'm not sure about the zooming, as it was designed to be a car DVR

Comment: Great! This very much sounds like something I am looking for. I'd just need to find out whether it has the zoom capability as it's the primary function I need. I don't care where it has been made as long as it serves the purpose. The link you have given above does not work (I found it on the web easily though).

Comment: Sadly I just found that it doesn't have any zoom capabilities.